# Top and bottom offset in image button not getting updated

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am creating a dynamic image button control. Below is my code.

```
           var deleteButton = new ImageButton(context);
           deleteButton.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Delete); 
           deleteButton.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
           deleteButton.OffsetTopAndBottom(-5);
           deleteButton.Layout(0, 0, 16, 16);
           deleteButton.SetMaxHeight(16); 
           //deleteButton.LayoutParameters.Height = 16; 
           inner.AddView(deleteButton);
```

None of the following make the image button size as image size.

```
Offsettopandbottom 
Setmaxheight 
layout (l,t,r,b)
```

Please refer attached image that I am using and the screen shot of the button output. The button is rectangular. It has top and bottom offset. How can I remove those. Please help.

Delete Image (16x16) - 
[image: Delete image]

Screen Shot -
[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different button background drawable in xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cross"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default_small"/>
```

Or in code:

```
deleteButton.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Drawable.ButtonDefaultSmall);
```

There will be no offset.